# What causes my function to return None at the end?

Tags: python, function

My very simple python function is returning `None` at the end of it and I'm not sure quite why. I've looked at some other posts and still can't figure it out.

Here is my code:

```
def printmult(n):
    i = 1
    while i <= 10:
        print (n * i, end = ' ')
        i += 1
    
print(printmult(30))
```

Comment: Because you don't return anything else.

Comment: Let me guess, you're a Ruby programmer and you're used to return the last statement in the method (without using `return` keyword) ;)

Comment: As BrenBarn stated, you didn't return any value, so the function returns `None`, to fix the problem with your code, you'll need to replace the last line with `printmult(30)`.

Answer (score 4):

Because in Python, every function returns a value, and `None` is what is returned if you don't explicitly specify something else.

What exactly did you *expect* `print(printmult(30))` to do? You've asked it to evaluate `printmult(30)`, and then `print` whatever results from that. *Something* has to result from it, right? Or were you maybe expecting some kind of exception to be raised?

Please be sure you understand that *printing and returning are not the same thing*.

Answer (score 3):

You are not returning anything in the function `printmult`, therefore when you print the *result* of `printmult(30)` it will be `None` (this is the default value returned when a function doesn't return anything explictly).

Since your method have a `print` statement inside and it's not supposed to return something (usually when a method names is something like `printSomething()`, it doesn't return anything), you should call it as:

```
printmult(30)
```

not

```
print(printmult(30))
```

Answer (score 3):

The other answers have done a good job of pointing out where the error is, i.e. you need to understand that printing and returning are not the same. If you want your function to *return* a value that you can then print or store in a variable, you want something like this:

```
def returnmult(n):
    i = 1
    result_string = ''
    while i <= 10:
        result_string += str(n * i) + ' '
        i += 1
    return result_string

print(returnmult(30))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def printmult(n):
    i = 1
    while i <= 10:
        print (n * i, end = ' ')
        i += 1

printmult(30)
```

The issue was that you were printing the return value of a function that returns nothing, which would print `None`

Comment: This still will print `None` when done at a REPL. Better to show someone how to _actually_ return a value so their original `print()` will work.

Answer (score -1):

I came from Ruby as well and it seems strange at first.

If you `print` something that has a `print` statement in it, the last thing it returns is `None`.

If you just **returned** the values and then invoked a `print` on the function it would not output `None`.

Hope this helps :)