# Use trained model as final layers without cross-validation concerns

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I currently have a custom tensorflow model *model_A* and I want to use it as the output of another model.  I want to cross-validate the entire new model without but I have the following problem:

---

If I define

```
model_copy= model_A
```

then train:

```
model_copy.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

then this impacts the original model.  I.e model_A.predict(X_train) will nolonger be equal to model_A.predict(X_train) after having trained model_copy... How to avoid this issue?

---

Details on my implementation:

After determining the best parameters by a randomized grid-search I do the following:

```
best_params = model1.best_params_

input_shape_model1 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(best_params['input_dim'],))

deep_readout = fullyConnected_Dense(best_params['height'])(input_shape_model1)

for i in range(best_params['depth']):
    # Activation
    layer= tf.nn.relu(layer)
    layer=fullyConnected_Dense(best_params['height'])(layer)

out_model1 = fullyConnected_Dense(1)(layer)

best_deep_readout_map = tf.keras.Model(input_shape_model1, out_model1)

opt_model1 = Adam(lr=best_params['learning_rate']) best_model1.compile(optimizer=opt_readout, loss="mae", metrics=["mse", "mae", "mape"])

best_model1.fit(X_concat,z_concat,                        epochs=best_params['epochs'],                    
 batch_size=
```

best_params['batch_size'])

After doing this... I try to save:

```
best_model1.save('~/Desktop/models/full_max/')
```

and I get this error:

---

**Error:**

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-208-c4e56870b2c0> in <module>
----> 1 best_deep_readout_map.save('~/Desktop/models/full_max/')

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/network.py in save(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer, save_format, signatures, options)    1006     """    1007     save.save_model(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer, save_format,
-> 1008                     signatures, options)    1009     1010   def save_weights(self, filepath, overwrite=True, save_format=None):

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/save.py in save_model(model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer, save_format, signatures, options)
    113   else:
    114     saved_model_save.save(model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer,
--> 115                           signatures, options)
    116 
    117 

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/saved_model/save.py in save(model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer, signatures, options)
     76     # we use the default replica context here.
     77     with distribution_strategy_context._get_default_replica_context():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
---> 78       save_lib.save(model, filepath, signatures, options)
     79 
     80   if not include_optimizer:

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/saved_model/save.py in save(obj, export_dir, signatures, options)
    897   # Note we run this twice since, while constructing the view the first time
    898   # there can be side effects of creating variables.
--> 899   _ = _SaveableView(checkpoint_graph_view)
    900   saveable_view = _SaveableView(checkpoint_graph_view)
    901 

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/saved_model/save.py in __init__(self, checkpoint_view)
    163     self.checkpoint_view = checkpoint_view
    164     trackable_objects, node_ids, slot_variables = (
--> 165         self.checkpoint_view.objects_ids_and_slot_variables())
    166     self.nodes = trackable_objects
    167     self.node_ids = node_ids

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/tracking/graph_view.py in objects_ids_and_slot_variables(self)
    416     object_names = object_identity.ObjectIdentityDictionary()
    417     for obj, path in path_to_root.items():
--> 418       object_names[obj] = _object_prefix_from_path(path)
    419     node_ids = object_identity.ObjectIdentityDictionary()
    420     for node_id, node in enumerate(trackable_objects):

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/tracking/graph_view.py in _object_prefix_from_path(path_to_root)
     62   return "/".join(
     63       (_escape_local_name(trackable.name)
---> 64        for trackable in path_to_root))
     65 
     66 

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/tracking/graph_view.py in <genexpr>(.0)
     62   return "/".join(
     63       (_escape_local_name(trackable.name)
---> 64        for trackable in path_to_root))
     65 
     66 

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/tracking/graph_view.py in _escape_local_name(name)
     55   # edges traversed to reach the variable, so we escape forward slashes in
     56   # names.
---> 57   return (name.replace(_ESCAPE_CHAR, _ESCAPE_CHAR + _ESCAPE_CHAR)
     58           .replace(r"/", _ESCAPE_CHAR + "S"))
     59 

**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will impact the original model because this is how Python works, it uses a reference, so practically they point to the same memory location.

If you want to make sure you have different models, regardless of what you intend to do with them, you can create a function that returns a specific model X.

E.g.

```
def retrieve_template_model():
   ...
   ...
   ...
   return model


model_1 = retrieve_template_model()
model_1.fit()
model_2 = retrieve_template_model()
#Here model 1 and model 2 are different, and you still have the weights trained for model 1
```

However, I recommend that you use `model.save()` to save the weights and the architecture together. At the same time, use `tf.keras.models.load_model()` in order to load the model and prevent retraining every time.

If you want to transfer the weights, you can use:

```
model_2.set_weights(model_1.get_weights())
```

Comment: But in this case I would have to re-fit the model1 every time... no?  

If i instead write: initialized_weights = modela.weights would that work?

Comment: Yes, that is why I recommended that you use model.save and model.load(). And if you want to do  with initialized_weights, check my updated answer from above :D

Comment: It sounds good but when I run:

model1.save('~/Desktop/models/full_max/')

I get the error:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: Did you correctly return the models from the function? This looks like more of Python error, if you don't return something from a function then Python automatically returns None. Check your function carefully.

Comment: Also have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24203750/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-replace

Comment: I updated my post, also I looked at the link but I can't see what the issue is..

Comment: Add the .hdf5/.h5 extension and tell me if the problem still persists. So full_path + "model.h5"

Comment: So like this: model1.save('~/Desktop/models/full_max/model1.h5')  (This didn't work for me)

Comment: In this stacktrace, it appears that not giving the name to the weights leads to this issue. You can find the answer in this link: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/26811

Comment: Well somehow it got fixed.  Maybe there was something even more subtle going on but either way I learned alot from this back&forth so thanks a huge amount :)

Comment: I am happy that you learned! This is how the community should always look like, a learning oasis :D

Comment: It really is honestly.  Thanks a lot again Timbus! :)