# For-Loop a list returning a None value in the end

Tags: list, function, python-2.7, for-loop, modulo

Why is it when executing this code, the final return is a None?

```
def evenNum(x):
    for num in x:
        if num%2==0:
            print num

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

print evenNum(a)
```

How do i omit that None value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Function Returning None](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21471876/python-function-returning-none)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you do not return any value in your function. If you want to have the list of even numbers you should do some thing like this:

```
def evenNum(x): 
  even_nums = []
  for num in x: 
    if num%2==0:
      even_nums.append(num)
      print num
  return even_nums
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function does not return anything, or, in other words, it returns `None`. Replace:

```
print evenNum(a)
```

with:

```
evenNum(a)
```

to avoid `None` being printed.

Answer (score 0):

`evenNum` - Its function returns no value, then the default is to return `None`