# Find the divisors: codewars

Tags: python

CodeWars problem:

> Create a function named divisors that takes an integer and returns an
> array with all of the integer's divisors(except for 1 and the number
> itself). If the number is prime return the string '(integer) is prime'

My code below runs perfectly when I tested it in Spyder3 for Python.

```
def divisors(integer):
    arr = []
    for x in range(2,integer - 1): #if integer is 12
        if integer % x == 0:
            arr.append(x)
        
    if len(arr) == 0:
        print(integer, 'is prime')
    else:    
        print(arr)
```

However, when I submit it to CodeWars, it returns the following error:

`divisors(15)` should return [3, 5]; my function does this. The CodeWars window log shows that the answer is right, but proceeds to say `None should equal [3, 5]`.

I checked to see if it was returning a something other than a list, but that checks out. Can anybody spot the problem?

Comment: You're not returning the array. Also, you need to divide while it is a factor. Make sure it returns `3, 3` for `9`, for example

Comment: Find+Replace All > print > return

Comment: @Artyer: I suspect that returning multiple divisors will get the solution rejected.  It asks for divisors, not prime factorization.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Function Returning None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21471876/python-function-returning-none)

Answer (score 3):

The site expects you to return a value from your function - while you just print it:

```
if len(arr) == 0:
    return str(integer) + ' is prime'
else:    
    return arr
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function returns `None` -- there is no `return` statement, no return value.  The default return value for a function is `None`, hence the error message you get.

```
def divisors(integer):
    arr = []
    for x in range(2,integer - 1): #if integer is 12
        if integer % x == 0:
            arr.append(x)

if len(arr) == 0:
    return str(integer) + ' is prime'
else:    
    return arr

for i in [1, 3, 9, 12, 64]:
    print (i, divisors(i))
```

Output:

```
1 1 is prime
3 3 is prime
9 [3]
12 [2, 3, 4, 6]
64 [2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
```

Comment: The specification says to return a string if the number is prime, not a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

*A **Meta Answer** to your question...*

Since every other answer has addressed the (obvious) main issue, I'd like to offer  an improvement to your existing algorithm (since this is codewars). [This link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/102760/454045) will explain why this code works.

```
def divisors(integer):
    arr = []
    for x in range(2, round(integer ** 0.5)): #if integer is 12
        if integer % x == 0:
            arr.append(x)

    if len(arr) == 0:
        return str(integer) + ' is prime'
    else:    
        return arr
```

A non-prime number will have factors only upto its square root in magnitude. This offers you complexity a little better than `O(n)`, and the improvement is markedly seen for very large inputs.

---

You can now look at shortening your code considerably with a list comprehension.

```
def divisors(integer):
    arr = [x for x in range(2, round(integer ** 0.5)) if integer % x == 0]

    if len(arr) == 0:
        return str(integer) + ' is prime'

    return arr
```

This does the same thing, but now the loop has been moved into the comprehension. The `else` is also redundant.

Comment: A bit too much to say for a comment, and also implicitly addresses the issue. :]

Comment: you could sum it as `iterate until `round(integer ** 0.5)` rather than `integer  - 1` [source]`. and there are a couple more improvements that could be put in place. I know the feeling that you want to share some really clever trick you've seen with OP - but answers are not the place.

Comment: @Uriel I completely get it. I've mentioned that my answer is only a meta answer. I still feel this'd be useful for future readers. You have my +1.

Comment: by the way, you could replace `if len(arr) == 0` with `if not arr`. though I do not suggest incorporating it into your answer

Comment: not really. using `if arr` to check that a dictionary, list or any other boolean convertible type is not empty is quite common, easy, *and* pythonic.