# I've been getting "NoneType object is not iterable" I have no idea why. I've checked my program a thousand times. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Tags: python

I've been given out an assignment to write a program for a byteadder. The first program just checks if the entered number is valid or not and imports two other modules which are logicGates and fullAdder. logicGates has no errors, I am sure of it since it consists of gates ( if, else) and nothing more. Here's my code:

```
    dec1=int(input("Enter first decimal number: "))
    dec2=int(input("Enter second decimal number: "))

    def check(dec1,dec2):

        if (dec1+dec2)>255:
            print ("The decimal number you've entered is invalid. Please enter another number")
            dec1=int(input("Enter first number again: "))
            dec2=int(input("Enter second number again: "))
            return dec1,dec2

        elif (dec1+dec2)>+127 and (dec1+dec2)<-127:
            print ("The decimal number you've entered is invalid. Please enter your numbers again")
            dec1=int(input("Enter first number again: "))
            dec2=int(input("Enter second number again: "))
            return dec1,dec2

        else:
            print("Your number is now converted")
            return dec1,dec2

            print (check(dec1,dec2))

            import conversion
            lis1, lis2=conversion.bin2dec(dec1,dec2)

            import fullAdder
            add= fullAdder.fulladder(lis1,lis2)

            print (add)
```

And here's my fullAdder:

```
    import logicGates

    def fulladder(bin1,bin2):
        lis1=list(bin1)
        lis2=list(bin2)
        Cin=0
        lisEmp=[]

        for i in range(7,-1,-1):
            num1=int(lis1[i])
            num2=int(lis2[i])
            result1=logicGates.XOR(num1,num2)
            result2=logicGates.NAND(result1,Cin)
            result3=logicGates.OR(result1,Cin)
            Sum=logicGates.AND(result2,result3)
            result4=logicGates.AND(num1,num2)
            result5=logicGates.AND(result1,Cin)
            result6=logicGates.NOR(result4,result5)
            result7=logicGates.NOT(result6)

            Cin=result7
            lisEmp.insert(0,Sum)

        return lisEmp
```

Here's my code for bin2dec:

```
    def bin2dec(dec1,dec2):

        a=bin(dec1)
        b=bin(dec2)

        c=a[2:]
        d=b[2:]

        bin1=c.zfill(8)
        bin2=d.zfill(8)

        print (bin1)
        print (bin2)
```

This is the error I keep getting.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python34\main.py", line 26, in <module>
        lis1, lis2=conversion.bin2dec(dec1,dec2)
    TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: `conversion.bin2dec` probably returns `None`.

Comment: Your indentation is off. It impossible to say what your code does.

Comment: check whether the conversion.bin2dec is returning any value first ? and provide the code for bin2dec

Comment: I've turned it on. @KlausD. Could you please help me out?

Comment: I've provided the code, Sir. Could you tell me what's wrong? @SamWilliamsJebaraj

Comment: When I check out the following code:

        print (conversion.bin2dec(lis1,lis2))

This is the error I get:

        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\Python34\main.py", line 29, in <module>
            add= fullAdder.fulladder(lis1,lis2)
        NameError: name 'lis1' is not defined

Comment: In the future, a [mcve] should have the **shortest possible code** that produces the same problem. This program is much more complex than the shortest thing that creates the same error.

Comment: return (bin1,bin2) at the end of the function will solve the problem. The function is not returning any value hence the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Function Returning None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21471876/python-function-returning-none)

Answer (score 2):

#### TLDR

The problem is that your function `bin2dec` does not have a return statement. You can fix it by adding

```
return bin1, bin2
```

to the end of `bin2dec`.

#### In depth explanation of the error

What actually happens, and why you get "NoneType object is not iterable", is that python does in fact *not* have multiple return values from a function, even if it looks like it. Instead, what happens is that a tuple is returned, and that this tuple is then unpacked.

So, what happens in your code is equivalent to this

```
result = conversion.bin2dec(dec1, dec2)
lis1, lis2 = result
```

Here, since you lack a return statement, we get that `result` is `None`, and then in the next line when `lis1, lis2 = result` is executed you try to unpack a `None` value, which is not possible and hence throws a `TypeError`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `bin2dec` function does not return values. It prints out values.

Try changing it to `return bin1, bin2`

Answer (score 0):

I think that code like this is better:

```
def input2num():
    while 1:
        dec1 = int(input("Enter first decimal number: "))
        dec2 = int(input("Enter second decimal number: "))
        if not -127 <= dec1+dec2 <= 127:
            print ("The decimal numbers you've entered is invalid."
                   " Please enter another two numbers.\n")
        else:
            print("Your number is now converted")                

            import conversion
            lst1, lst2 = conversion.bin2dec(dec1, dec2)

            import fullAdder
            add = fullAdder.fulladder(lst1, lst2)
            print(add)
            return dec1, dec2

dec1, dec2 = input2num()
```

fullAdder:

```
import logicGates

def fulladder(bin1, bin2):
    cin, lstEmp = 0, []
    for a, b in zip(bin1[::-1], bin2[::-1]): 
        num1, num2 = int(a), int(b)
        result1 = logicGates.XOR(num1, num2)
        result2 = logicGates.NAND(result1, cin)
        result3 = logicGates.OR(result1, cin)
        _sum = logicGates.AND(result2, result3)
        result4 = logicGates.AND(num1, num2)
        result5 = logicGates.AND(result1, cin)
        result6 = logicGates.NOR(result4, result5)
        result7 = logicGates.NOT(result6)
        cin = result7
        lstEmp.append(_sum)
    return lstEmp[::-1]
```

bin2dec:

```
def bin2dec(dec1, dec2):
    form = lambda x: bin(x)[2:].zfill(8)
    print(form(dec1), form(dec2))
    return form(dec1), form(dec2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def bin2dec(dec1,dec2):

        a=bin(dec1)
        b=bin(dec2)

        c=a[2:]
        d=b[2:]

        bin1=c.zfill(8)
        bin2=d.zfill(8)

        print (bin1)
        print (bin2)
```

There is no return statement in your function. Hence when it is called after execution it returns a None Value.

You can fix it by adding return(bin1,bin2) after the print

```
def bin2dec(dec1,dec2):

            a=bin(dec1)
            b=bin(dec2)

            c=a[2:]
            d=b[2:]

            bin1=c.zfill(8)
            bin2=d.zfill(8)

            print (bin1)
            print (bin2)
            return (bin1,bin2)
```