# Apply method for pandas

Tags: python, pandas, function, apply

i am having a problem while working with apply method. so, i am trying to make the first and last letter of a series uppercase. First i have made a simple series i.e

```
s1 = pd.Series(['pandas','python','javascript','c#'])
s1
```

The output:

```
0        pandas
1        python
2    javascript
3            c#
dtype: object
```

When I make a simple function and run it. It works fine with no issue and gives me the output that I was hoping for.

```
def upp(x):
for i in x:
    print(f'{i[0].upper()}{i[1:-1].lower()}{i[-1].upper()}')

upp(s1)
```

Output:

```
PandaS
PythoN
JavascripT
C#
```

However, the output is not a series type, as I would want it to do further analysis. I ran a type method to check the type.

```
type(upp(s1))
```

Output:

```
NoneType
```

So, i guessed i have to use the apply method to get a series datatype. But, when i run apply method with the function. the result was not what i was hoping for.

```
def upp(x):
for i in x:
    print(f'{i[0].upper()}{i[1:-1].lower()}{i[-1].upper()}')
s1.apply(upp)
```

Output:

```
PP
HH
PP
PP
YY
TT
HH
OO
NN
JJ
AA
VV
AA
CC
##
0    None
1    None
2    None
3    None
dtype: object
```

Can anyone explain to me what is happening and where i am doing wrong and give more information on how to use and not use apply method? I am a beginner and practicing some questions. It will be a great help to understand this concept.

Comment: your function is just printing the result of `'{i[0].upper()}{i[1:-1].lower()}{i[-1].upper()}'`, and doesn't return anything. That's why the type of your output is `NoneType`. You should be using `return` additionally or instead of `print(...)`

Comment: related: [Python Function Returning None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21471876/python-function-returning-none)

Comment: When using `.apply` on a `Series`, the function used is receiving one element of the series at a time, so the `for` loop in `upp` now iterates over individual characters of each value in the series, not over the series' elements themselves.

Comment: FYI: When someone answers your question, please "accept it" if the answer is helpful. (click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in) [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: i didnt know, we can do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function prints the result instead of returning it using `return`. Furthermore, the `for` loop is extra in your function as the `.apply` method applies the function to one item at a time.

You can change your function to:

```
def upp(x):
    return f'{x[0].upper()}{x[1:-1].lower()}{x[-1].upper()}'

s1.apply(upp)
```

Or, you can simply use a lambda function:

```
s1.apply(lambda x: f'{x[0].upper()}{x[1:-1].lower()}{x[-1].upper()}')
```

Comment: thanks.. i finally got it. i thought to pass all the values of a series we  need to use a loop and then only we can pass them all. Nobody told or i think i missed it, when we pass a series to a function, it  works on every element.

Comment: @Samrat Thapa: BTW, looping using the `.apply` method is much faster compared to crude looping over the DataFrame using a `for` loop. (search "vectorization" for more information)

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there. The below answer could help:

```
import pandas as pd


s1 = pd.Series(['pandas','python','javascript','c#'])


def upp(x):
    return f'{x[0].upper()}{x[1:-1].lower()}{x[-1].upper()}'

s1 = s1.apply(upp)

print(s1)
```

Output:

```
0        PandaS
1        PythoN
2    JavascripT
3            C#
dtype: object
```

You don't need to use loop in `upp()`.